# No Response From REST Client for a REST API

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, rest, jakarta-ee

[image]Hi am trying to test a REST Api using Firefox REST Client. But it does not return me any response. Below is the scenario as to how it should work.

When I post an xml file through Rest client, It should send me a response code saying success or error and save the xml file data into the database. This is working in everyone else machine, but am not sure why it is not working in mine.

> ```
>    https://localhost:8443/web/services/activities
> ```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Asking the obvious question:  Do you have the REST service running on localhost, or are you trying to connect to it on another machine?  If you know it's running correctly on another machine, perhaps you can insert that IP address instead of localhost as a sanity check.

Comment: Its not running on the localhost too, when I give  https://localhost:8443/web/services/activities, its giving me  405 error

Comment: If the REST service isn't running on localhost, the query will fail.  You have to put in the URL for the machine where the REST service is running.

Comment: ok. there is a test server where the webservice is running, even if i use that url in my REST client, it responds me nothing. https://11.37.66.135:8443/web

Comment: That test server doesn't appear to be accessible to me.  I think you'll need to get help from someone locally, one of the many people you mention who have it working.  Compare settings, etc. to make sure you're doing the right things.  I'm sorry I don't have any other suggestions.